# Half open intervals generated sigma algebra $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $S_{d}$ be the empty set plus all sets of the form  $$
>  (a_{1},b_{1}]\times\cdots\times(a_{d},b_{d}]\subset\mathbb{R}^{d} $$ 
>   where $-\infty\leq a_{i}<b_{i}\leq\infty$.
>
> I want to show that $\sigma$-algebra generated by $S_{d}$ is Borel
>   $\sigma$-algebra in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

What I know is $S_{d}$ is semi-algebra. And to use Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$
system, I know $S_{1}$and $S_{d}$ is $\pi$-system.

Then I guess I should use induction.

What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^d$.

Let $J_U$ denote the collection of sets $(a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times(a_d,b_d]$ that are subsets of $U$ and secondly satisfy $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb Q$ for $i=1,\dots,d$.

Then $J_U$ is countable and it can be shown that: $$U=\bigcup_{V\in J_U}V$$

This proves that open set $U$ is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the sets of the form $(a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times(a_d,b_d]$.

So if $\tau$ denotes the topology and $\mathcal A:=\sigma(S_d)$  then $\tau\subseteq\mathcal A$ and consequently $\sigma(\tau)\subseteq\mathcal A$. Here $\sigma(\tau)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

The other side I leave up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is your $\mathcal{A}$ denoting sigma algebra generated by $S_d$?

Comment: Yes i mean it is that one

Comment: For the other side, should I show $S_{d}\subset\sigma(\tau)$?

Comment: Yes. That is enough.